# Problem of RollPitchYawAngles and orthogonalize

Tags: linear-algebra, rotation

```
mat = {{-0.49725257909203024`, -0.2043300848952244`, 
   0.8432016893917105`}, {-0.10379348012824717`, 0.9789020478164747`, 
   0.17600481318299097`}, {-0.8613749418705233`, 
   1.0525252113904133`*^-8, -0.5079696935030202`}}
```

`mat` is an approximately orthogonal matrix, it's generated by a rotation matrix system, just because of the accuracy in data export cause the mat is not an OrthogonalMatrix in default(high) `Tolerance` of `OrthogonalMatrixQ`.

`RollPitchYawAngles[mat]` will give no results with error info, because `mat` is not a valid `RotationMatrix` see in the image at the end of the post.

`matO` is orthogonalized from mat to an orthogonal matrix.

```
RollPitchYawAngles[mat]=Error Informations
OrthogonalMatrixQ[mat]=False 
matO=Orthogonalize[mat]
RollPitchYawAngles[matO]=Give a valid results
```

Methods options can be found in HelpPage, I think everyone wanna play this quesion might see the HelpPage.

Actually, the problem is the tolerance.

I have some questions,

Question1:
Can I set tolerance in `RollPitchYawAngles`? like Tolerance option in `OrthogonalMatrixQ` ?
[image]

`RollPitchYawAngles[mat]` will give no results, because mat is not a valid RotationMatrix. If we have tolerance setting, maybe we no longer need `Orthogonalize`

```
RollPitchYawAngles[mat, Tolerance->10^-5]
RollPitchYawAngles[mat, Precision->10^-5]
```

Question2:
Is the manipulation of orthogonalize safe?
I found different Method setting of `Orthogonal` might give different results.

Might the rotation direction is different in the final axis, but the final state is the same, I'm not sure.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code instead of  picture.

Comment: @cvgmt The core codes are the `mat`, and the functions I've pasted, other codes are not important, just my personal test for evidence and I added some.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the orthogonal matrix `matO` that is closest to the matrix `mat` by a singular-value decomposition (see, for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2215359/632893) for details):

```
mat = {{-0.49725257909203024`, -0.2043300848952244`, 0.8432016893917105`},
      {-0.10379348012824717`, 0.9789020478164747`, 0.17600481318299097`},
      {-0.8613749418705233`, 1.0525252113904133`*^-8, -0.5079696935030202`}};

{u, σ, v} = SingularValueDecomposition[mat]
(*    {{{-0.74587, -0.0650789, -0.662904},
        {0.557697, -0.60519, -0.568083},
        {-0.364213, -0.793416, 0.487688}},
       {{1., 0., 0.},
        {0., 1., 0.},
        {0., 0., 1.}},
       {{0.626725, 0.778604, -0.031488},
        {0.698335, -0.579124, -0.420647},
        {-0.345753, 0.24164, -0.906678}}}    *)

matO = u . Transpose[v]
(*    {{-0.497253, -0.20433, 0.843202},
       {-0.103793, 0.978902, 0.176005},
       {-0.861375, 1.00106*10^-8, -0.50797}}    *)
```

The matrix `matO` is very close to `mat`:

```
Norm[mat - matO]
(*    5.04973*10^-9    *)
```

It is orthogonal by construction:

```
OrthogonalMatrixQ[matO]
(*    True    *)
```

We can calculate its roll/pitch/yaw angles:

```
RollPitchYawAngles[matO]
(*    {2.75171, 1.00321, -2.80805}    *)
```

#### Update

As @UlrichNeumann points out in the comments, we can compute `matO` more directly with

```
matO = Transpose[Inverse[mat]] . MatrixPower[Transpose[mat] . mat, 1/2]
```

which gives exactly the same result as the SVD.

Comment: Yes, `mat` is actually a RotationMatrix but exported with low accuracy and re-imported into `Mathematica`, so `Orthogonalize[mat]` gives very close to `mat` seems valid in this case. But `Orthogonalize` depends on methods we choose.

Comment: @HyperGroups did you mean to comment on @DanielHuber's answer? I'm not using `Orthogonalize` because I don't think it's the right tool for this job.

Comment: I see, your `matO` is constructed by SVD

Comment: Yes, `matO` is constructed by minimizing the Frobenius distance between `mat` and the space of orthogonal matrices. Effectively this can be done by SVD.

Comment: @Roman Nice answer! I expected `matO` by evaluating the polar decomposition `Transpose[ Inverse[mat]] . Sqrt[Transpose[mat] . mat] ` but result deviates slightly, no idea why.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann did you mean `matO = Transpose[Inverse[mat]] . MatrixPower[Transpose[mat] . mat, 1/2]`? Yes, this seems to generate the exact same result as the SVD, thanks!

Comment: @Roman Thanks for your answer! Silly mistake using `Sqrt[Transpose[mat] . mat] `

Comment: @UlrichNeumann but isn't the easiest/quickest way to compute a matrix-square-root through a SVD? Your method is quite a bit slower than the direct SVD route.

Comment: @Roman Agreed but the formula follows directly `A=A^-t .(A^t.A)^(1/2).(A^t.A)^(1/2)=R.S` , (R: Rotationmatrix (R^t .R=I ) , S: sym. matrix) ,without further knowledge of matrix algebra. Thereby one can show that ||A-R|| is small ( minimal rotation)

Answer (score 1):

Question 1.

What should the tolerance due in case of "RollPitchYawAngles". This simply gives you 3 numbers, no tolerance involved.

Question 2.

The given matrix has rows (or columns) that constitute only approximately a tripod. To make an accurate  tripod one has to rotate the rows (columns) a bit. This can  be done in an infinite numbers of ways, none better than the other. E.g. one can apply Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization: Take one of the vectors and normalize it. Take one of the remaining vectors, subtract from it the projection onto the first normalized vector and normalize. Take the last vector, subtract the projections onto the first and second vectors and normalize.

As you can see, this is what "Orthogonalize" does:

```
NumberForm[mat, 12]
```

[image]

```
NumberForm[Orthogonalize[mat], 12]
```

[image]

The first row remains unchanged, but the second and third a rotated.

Comment: `RollPitchYawAngles[mat]` will give no results, because mat is not a valid `RotationMatrix`. If we have tolerance setting, maybe we no longer need `Orthogonalize`